# Does Jackrabbit provide faceted search?

Tags: jackrabbit, faceted-search

I am exploring the features of Apache Jackrabbit to be used in one of my projects. One of the features that I would require is a faceted search implementation based on the metadata stored in the content repository. Does Jackrabbit provide any out of the box faceted search implementation? Or should I need to go for Apache solr or some other search engine for obtaining the faceted search feature. Any Jackrabbit experts out there, who have faced similar challenge ?

Answer (score 1):

The default search engine provided with Jackrabbit is lucene.  This guide to doing [faceted search with lucene](http://nsdl.org/nsdl_dds/services/ddsws1-1/facet_userguide.html) may prove helpful to you.